# It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library

Tags: react-native, npm, node-modules, cryptojs

The package at `node_modules\crypto-js\core.js` attempted to import the Node standard library module `crypto`. It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/workflow/using-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries

Getting this error when running `npm start`

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

for expo instead of crypto you can use `expo-crypto`
you can install it as below
`expo install expo-crypto`

in your codes

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as Crypto from 'expo-crypto';
  
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const digest = await Crypto.digestStringAsync(
        Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA256,
        'Github stars are neat'
      );
      console.log('Digest: ', digest);
      /* Some crypto operation... */
    })();
  }, []);
...

as from expo documentation
```