# Android Bundling failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, powershell, expo

I'm trying to run a react Native mobile application on android. I'm new to app development. I was previously able to run it, but after making some changes it's not possible anymore.

I'm following the tutorial on the expo website, here: https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/image-picker/. I'm on step 4.

This is the error that I'm getting in powershell, here:

`Android Bundling failed 3813ms The package at "node_modules\@expo\config-plugins\build\android\EasBuild.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "fs". It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.`

On my phone's expo go app, I get a 500 error code.

These are the previous links I've tried to help me solve this problem without success.

[It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379748/it-failed-because-the-native-react-runtime-does-not-include-the-node-standard-li)

[The package at "node_modules\uuidv4\build\lib\uuidv4.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "util"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65989398/the-package-at-node-modules-uuidv4-build-lib-uuidv4-js-attempted-to-import-the)

https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/96 (some of the comments on this thread are difficult for me to understand. But, I'm also worried about making too many changes where I won't remember how to go back and fix those changes).

Thanks for reading! I will happily give information that was missing here.

---

EDIT:

//**ImageViewer.js**
changing my ImageViewer.js file from the code that is directed below to the code that is at **originalImageViewer.js** makes my app work again on my phone.

```
import { Styles } from '@expo/config-plugins/build/android';
import { StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function ImageViewer({ placeholderImageSource, selectedImage }) {
  const imageSource = selectedImage !== null
  ? {uri: selectedImage }
  : placeholderImageSource;
  return <Image source={imageSource} style={styles.image} />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: 320,
    height: 440,
    borderRadius: 18,
  },
});
```

//**originalImageViewer.js**

```
import { StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function ImageViewer({ placeholderImageSource }) {
  return (
    <Image source={placeholderImageSource} style={styles.image} />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: 320,
    height: 440,
    borderRadius: 18,
  },
});
```

Comment: So this: "_but after making some changes it's not possible anymore_" should provide a clue. Either explicitly detail the changes you made or go back to the working configuration and change incrementally until the one step that breaks it can be identified. Report you findings.

Comment: Hi Randy, your advice hit the nail on the head! I went back and changed my ImageViewer.js file to the previous step which was Step 4 in the expo tutorial docs, here: https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/build-a-screen/. As compared to the changes I made in step 4 on the next page, here: https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/image-picker/.

Comment: Hi @LLStevieJ , i'm the maintainer of react-native-dotenv and author of the tagged issue. The error is correct- there generally should be no need for `fs`. I am glad you were able to resolve this. Can you please move your Edit2 to an answer and mark it as resolved? That way I can direct other people with your question to this link.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line: import { Styles } from '@expo/config-plugins/build/android'; from ImageViewer.js makes my code work normally! Solution found. In fact, that line shouldn't have been there in the first place, I must've added it when I was very tired. The expo tutorial docs don't include it.